# Маска подсети по количеству узлов

Tags: сеть, ip, cisco

Прохожу курс Cisco и решаю интерактивное задание, не могу понять я верно решил и у них какой-то затык(такое было пару раз уже), либо я не понял тему.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, прав я или нет и в чем я не прав, если так.

upd, исправил с 10-ю хостами, но всё так же :

upd 2, извините за невнимательность, поправил маску :[image: еще скрин]

Comment: У вас не хватит адресов на 10 хостов, остальное выглядит верным

Comment: @vasyaPetrov_0x366784:
проверяйте используя, например, **ipcalc**.

Comment: @Mike, обновил, скрин, могу я сказать, что у них кривая проверка или я опять накосячил?

Comment: @vasyaPetrov_0x366784  Для 10 адресов у вас маска 224, а должна быть 240. Пользуйтесь обычным калькулятором под windows, в режиме "программист", там на биты кликаешь и видишь тут же в десятичном виде все.

Comment: @Mike, поправил и всё одно.

Comment: @vasyaPetrov_0x366784 Но у вас внизу картинки явная надпись "Верно" ...

Comment: @Mike, да, спасибо. Больше не буду допоздна засиживаться. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

с десятичными числами считать сложнее, с двоичными или префиксом — проще.

например, префикс 24 бита.

значит, «свободных» бит — 32 минус 24. то есть, 8 (соответствует количеству нулей в двоичном представлении маски).

а это 256 ip-адресов (2 в восьмой степени).

учитывая, что первый ip-адрес (под)сети зарезервирован для идентификации (под)сети, а последний ip-адрес зарезервирован в качестве широковещательного адреса, остаётся 254 адреса для машин в такой (под)сети.

дальше считайте по аналогии.

Comment: Да я вроде как понял уже, но не достаточно уверен для того чтобы им написать о том, что у них что-то не так, чтобы другие не мучились если что. Потому спрашиваю. Но всё равно спасибо.